# Export SharePoint 2010 WebPart data to Excel using a sandbox solution

Tags: 2010, web-part

I am trying to create a sandboxed webpart to export data from another webpart within the webpart page to Excel.

I tried [using the Excel ActiveXObject in a client-side script](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=187838), but it requires this META tag to be added:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="application/vnd.ms-excel">
```

How can I get this script to work? Alternatively is there another solution?

**Note that it is enough if the solution works only in Internet Explorer, but I cannot change the security settings.**

Answer (score 1):

The metadata mentioned is merely to specify what kind of content the stream has. It is also used when trying to download a file. By example, more is in *[HTML <meta> http-equiv Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)*.

Use it in the HEAD section of your page, as in:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-disposition": attachment; filename="file.xls">
</head>
```

In code, however, you use it as such:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
    "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=:" + '"' + "text/html; charset=utf-8" + '"' + "></head>");

// BUILD YOUR STRING HERE

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I am not sure about an alternative just yet. I shall investigate in that direction.